# Почём же овощи недотушены / не дотушены?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

> Почём же овощи недотушены / не дотушены?

> Отчего ты супчик недосолил / не досолил?

> Почему же рыбёшка недожарена / не дожарена?

Вот подарочек вам: https://youtu.be/JZqa4aVto_8?si=62R1NUfjfk4YUpCc.